# Reading Excel file using POI EventModel

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I would like to read Excel files (.xls format) using Apache POI's HSSF EventModel. My excel sheet is a simple excel file with no macros. Just wanted to know what types of RECORDS I have to take care of.

Following are types of data in the excel file:-

```
    1. String
    2. Boolean
    3. Number
    4. Date.
```

I found these BoolErr,Blank,Number. Let me know which else record i have to take care of.

Thanks
Srinivasan

Comment: What kind of things do you want out of your file though? Text? Numbers? Formatting? Styles? Sheet Names? Links? Images? Your requirements for what to get out largely dictate which records matter...

Comment: I want only text,date & numbers no styles,no images,no styles..etc

Comment: The raw floating point numbers, or the numbers as they look in excel? Also, raw Excel dates (days since 1900/1904), or dates as they look in Excel?

Comment: Number & dates as they look in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want numbers and dates to show up as they do in Excel, then you need all the cell formatting information. This is because both numeric and date cells are stored the same way, as floating point numbers one cell per record (except in a few special cases around MulRks), and it's only the formatting rules that tell you if it's a date or a number and how to display them.

What I'd suggest you do is look at two excellent examples for Event Based extraction of .xls files using the HSSF Event Model. The first is in POI itself, [EventBasedExcelExtractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/EventBasedExcelExtractor.java) which provides plain text output. The 2nd is in Apache Tika, [ExcelExtractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ExcelExtractor.java), which provides an XHTML version

In both, you'll see code that registers and handles only a few of the Record SIDs, and you'll also see what they get used for. You'll also see how to get access to POI's formatting code when using the Event Model, which you'll need to use to get your numbers and dates to look correct.

You might also want to look at another POI example, [XLS2CSVmra](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java), which shows how to deal with the fact that rows and cells that haven't been used generally don't show up in Excel files. For text extraction that's not an issue, but for things like CSV export knowing that cells or rows are missing, and how many is key!